# Execute javascript on html partial render in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get some elements of a partial whenever it is rendered. The problem is that I can use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {});` when the whole page is rendered but I am not able to figure out how to get the elements everytime the html partial is rendered.

**js code**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  document.querySelectorAll('answer_choices');
});
```

How can I call this event whenever the partial is rendered. I can include the javascript file in the partial itself but it creates a lot of overhead. So this javascript file is included in the main html file but I want the `querySelectorAll` function to be triggered whenever the html partial is rendered. How can I do the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jquery - you can do it in that way:

```js
$(function() {
   document.querySelectorAll('answer_choices');
})
```

Comment: Actually I have the task of migrating from jQuery to vanilla js. That's why I'm using vanilla js.

Comment: So you can use the source code of that Jquery function :)
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ad6a94c3f1747829082b85fd53ee2efbae879707/src/core/ready.js#L80-L93

Comment: Ok. Is there anyway to find out if a part of html is reloaded without reloading the whole page in vanilla javascript?